# Force TCNT to stay below OCRxA on ATmega328P

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, atmega328, timers, avr

I'm using a timer and the `TIMERx_COMPA` ISR to generate a signal in "the background".

This ISR is triggered when the timer reaches a certain value (`OCRxA`), which in turn can be changed by the user.
Once the ISR triggers, the timer is reset and the next waiting period occurs.

If the compare value (`OCRxA`) is changed to a value below the current timer value before having hit the old compare value, the timer keeps running until it overflows back to 0 and hits the new `OCRxA` value. This results in no signal being generated until the timer has looped around, which can be quite long for the 16-bit `TIMER1` timer.

There are multiple way to get around this:

1. Reset `TCNTx` to zero whenever `OCRxA`. Easy, but one signal will always be off-clock
2. If `TCNTx` is greater than `OCRxA` (after changing `OCRxA`), reset it to just below `OCRxA`
3. If `TCNTx` is greater than `OCRxA`, trigger the interrupt manually, where the signal is generated and `TCNTx` is reset

I belive the third option would be the cleanest, both in checking whether the issue has occured as well as for the signal quality.

This is certainly an `X -> Y` problem, so I'm open for other approaches.

My question, for now, would be:
**Can I manually jump to an ISR regardless of its "normal" trigger?**

Comment: @Juraj True, I suppose the "Electrical Engineering" SE would've been more appropriate?
I am programming an Arduino Uno with the Arduino IDE though.
I've always felt the line between those two SEs is very thin, especially when using the Arduino as nothing but a simple way to program the AVR.

Comment: I ask AVR specific questions on https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I manually jump to an ISR regardless of its "normal" trigger?

This should be possible, but is probably not the best solution.

> This is certainly an `X -> Y` problem, so I'm open for other
>   approaches.

It would seem you are using the timer in CTC mode. In this mode, when
you write to `OCRxA`, the register is updated immediately, which leads
to the problem you are experiencing. The solution is to instead set the
timer to “fast PWM” mode. In fast PWM mode, the `OCRxA` register is
double buffered: you will be actually writing to a buffer register, and
`OCRxA` is automatically updated from that buffer on the same timer
clock cycle that clears the counter.

It may sound counter-intuitive to use a PWM mode when you do not need
the PWM feature. However, as long as the “compare output mode” is set to
“normal port operation” for both channels, the timer will not generate
any PWM output, and you can legitimately use the fast PWM mode only for
its double buffer feature.

Comment: That's absolutely gorgeous.
It seems to work perfectly with my test code, without ever checking whether `TCNT` has reached past `OCRxA`.

The buffers delay would be irrelevant with `OCRxA` only being updated once per millisecond.

I'm a bit ashamed to admit I wasn't even using CTC though, the entire code had been in "normal" (mode 0), with me resetting `TCNT` as the first action in the ISR.
You were refering to "mode 4" where I could have just omitted the `TCNT` reset, right?

Comment: I had some code which would check for how long `TCNT` was larger than `OCRxA` and output that over serial.
This now "always" displays some of that "lag".
Am I right in assuming it's comparing my **real** `TCNT` value to the **buffered** `OCRxA` and not the **active** `OCRxA` and that this metric would now be meaningless / expected?

If so, is there any way of reading the "active" `OCRxA` vs. the  one in the buffer which is not yet "active"?

Comment: @TobiasWeiß: Re “_the entire code had been in "normal" (mode 0) [...]._”: Since the ISR prologue takes some time, and may even be delayed by other interrupts, your interrupt period is likely to be larger than you want. “_You were refering to "mode 4" [...], right?_” Right. “_Am I right in assuming it's comparing my **real** `TCNT` value to the **buffered** `OCRxA` [...]?_” Judging from the section “Output Compare Units” of the datasheet, it would seem this is the case. “_Is there any way of reading the "active" OCRxA [...]?_” Not that I am aware of.